# Ubuntu mate 21.10, is bug? all apps maximized, control buttons are off screen

Tags: ubuntu-mate

I use 2 monitors, and the problem occurs on both, when I maximize any window, the buttons (minimize, maximize and close) are above or outside the monitor's view, so I can't click on them

I use the bar at the top, on one of the screens, and on that screen, when maximizing any window, the buttons mentioned are under the bar

[image: caja's maximized screen]

--xxxxxx---

[image: full screen, both screen]

Comment: As a workaround, you can press `ctrl` and drag the full screened window with your mouse.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the monitors require slight adjustment. LCD monitors usually has an auto adjust to make these small adjustments. Or, perhaps the x _ and little square are not configure to appear. With gnome3, if you press `ALT+F7` keys, the arrows will move the window. Then, if the control symbols are there, you can see them.